# Adding fields to register form in laravel won't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, registration

I have been trying to add some extra fields into my register form in Laravel but it won't work. I don't get any errors the page just returns back to me and nothing uploads to my database.

I had this working normally when I first set up Laravel but as soon as I tried to add extra fields it would not work anymore. I have posted my code below.

RegisterController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'dateofbirth' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'Level' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'dateofbirth' => $data['dateofbirth'], 
            'level' => $data['level'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Migrations

```
        <?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('dateofbirth');
                $table->string('level');            
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        }
    }
```

Register.blade.php

```
             <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('dateofbirth') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="dateofbirth" class="col-md-4 control-label">D.O.B</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="dateofbirth" type="dateofbirth" class="form-control" name="dateofbirth" value="{{ old('datebirth') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('dateofbirth'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('dateofbirth') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                              <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('level') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="level" class="col-md-4 control-label">Level</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="level" type="level" class="form-control" name="level" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('level'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('level') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: doe's any validation errors are occurring?

Comment: did you set the protected $fillable in your Model?

Comment: no , I dont get any errors and I checked the laravel.log as well. @ab_ab

Comment: yes @mchev : protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'dateofbirth', 'level' 'password',
    ];

Comment: probably validation errors are not logged to the laravel.log. confirm it with `dd($errors->all())` in your view file.

Comment: tried this @ab_ab still nothing appears

Comment: does the request enters the `create` method?

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean? nothing posts to my database and I don't get any errors @ab_ab

Comment: put a `dd($data);` inside the `protected function create(array $data)` as the first statement and submit the form and check what it returns..

Comment: Just a tip: your validation is using `Level` instead of `level`. Also, you added the fields to this migration instead of creating a new migration. Did you reset the migrations?

Comment: @NiamhFlannery can you post your routes.php (or the at least the route definitions for the controller)?

Comment: @GoogleMac Thanks spotted this error too and it solved the problem

Comment: @NiamhFlannery why you are using input type="level" using number or text

Comment: No reason for this I changed it to text in the end. however using type=level did not effect the functionality of my registration form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a tip: your validation is using `Level` instead of `level`. Also, you added the fields to this migration instead of creating a new migration. Did you reset the migrations?

Comment: yes I manually imported the table as this was easier for me to do. I have the registration form all working now. Thanks